# Angular test - how to mock document.getElementbyId in angular test?

Tags: angular, angular-test

I have below two lines in one of the functions in angular component. My angular tests are failing throwing the error    TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value').

```
test.ts

function reset(){
 (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('test1')).value = '';
 this.nameCtrl.setValue(null);
}

test.spec

fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.test1.value='';
fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.nameCtrl.setValue(null);
```

I tried to mock the lines in rest using the above by it still fails. Please help

Comment: I don't understand how test.ts and test.spec are related. Where is the component? Do you have `orgTeam` instantialized?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Angular `ViewChild` decorator instead of `document.getElementById` for accessing the test1 DOM element.

See an example here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-viewchild-access-component